# is there an equivalent of rspec's let for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, rspec, python-unittest

In RSpec, you can lazily set variables using a memoized helper method. The syntax is called a [let block](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let). It looks like this:

```
describe "trucks" do
  let(:truck) { create(:truck) }
  let(:car) { create(:car) }

  it "has the same number of wheels as cars" do
    expect(car.wheels).to eq(truck.wheels)
  end

  it "has the same fuel type as cars" do
    expect(car.fuel_type).to eq(truck.fuel_type)
  end

  it "has power steering" do
    expect(truck.power_steering).to eq(true)
  end

end
```

What's nice about it is that I automatically only create the car for the examples where I use the car, because it's lazily evaluated.

I'd like to do the same thing in python. At the moment, the only way I know to share setup between tests is with a setup block. This executes for all examples in the group.

```
class TrucksTestCase(TestCase):
  def setup(self):
    self.truck = TruckFactory()
    self.car = CarFactory()

  def test_has_same_number_of_wheels_as_cars(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.car.wheels, self.truck.wheels)

  def test_has_same_fuel_type_as_cars(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.car.fuel_type, self.truck.fuel_type)

  def test_has_power_steering(self):
    self.assertTrue(self.truck.power_steering)
```

With this setup, we create the car even for the third test case, which does not use it. Is there a way around this?

Comment: with pytest you can have a fixture that is used in a specific test

Comment: but also you normally have the test classes that are centered around their setup method, a rare exception is large setups (eg sample database). you can redesign the test classes, but if that does not suit your needs, use fixtures

Answer (score 0):

One approach is just to have functions.  They won't be executed until you explicitly call them, i.e. lazy e.g.

```py
def car():
  return CarFactory

def truck():
  return TruckFactory

class TrucksTestCase(TestCase):

  def test_has_same_number_of_wheels_as_cars(self):
    self.assertEqual(car().wheels, truck().wheels)

  def test_has_same_fuel_type_as_cars(self):
    self.assertEqual(car().fuel_type, truck().fuel_type)

  def test_has_power_steering(self):
    self.assertTrue(truck().power_steering)
```